# How do I password protect an external-hard-drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password Protecting Partitions on an External Hard Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/68086/password-protecting-partitions-on-an-external-hard-drive)

Yesterday I bought an external hard drive, an ADATA 640 GB superior sh 93, but it does not include any hardware or software password-protection.  Is it possible to set up some form of software password protection for it?

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: If you are using Windows 7, you can use Bitlocker To-Go.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to approach this; your question was a bit vague.   I believe you are trying to keep others from accessing data on an external HDD.  If this is the case then I would recommend you download a copy of [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) and create an encrypted, password protected, container on your external drive.  An added benefit of TrueCrypt is that it is cross platform so it will work regardless of your OS.

Comment: does this protection work on all pc s or just the pc that it would be installed?