# How to cut off access for one user to one particular partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, user-accounts, windows-8.1

How can I cut off access for one particular user to one partition on Windows 8.1?

I created a GuestUser account (Prey did it for me), but it is a local user (without administrator permissions), because I want him to connect to WiFi networks. However, I want him to be blocked from using the D: partition, particularly: opening, executing, editing, deleting and adding files which are on it.

How can I restrict access for just this user account?

Comment: As an Administrator change the permissions on the drive itself so that the User/Guest user groups don't have access to the account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password Protecting Partitions on an External Hard Drive](http://superuser.com/questions/68086/password-protecting-partitions-on-an-external-hard-drive)

Comment: @Mokubai: I disagree. That other question is answered with encryption, and that is the appropriate answer for that question. _This_ question is more appropriately answered with access control; it assumes/implies that the targeted user does not have administrator privileges or physical access to the drive.

Comment: @Scott encryption is just as valid an answer as ACLs and as such I voted to close, if you think ACLs are a better answer then why don't you show us how to implement them to meet the questioners purpose?

Comment: For this problem I used user groups management. I solved it, by creating additional user group for GuestUser account. Then I set his permissions for having no access to other partition files.

Comment: @wojciechowskip: Our typical reaction to a statement like that is: submit it as an answer, and then accept it. The more detail you write, the more useful it will be to the next person who has this question (or a similar one). And you might want to hurry, because the question is on its way to being closed; once that happens, you will not be able to submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said before, I used standard user group management and their permission.

1. I created additional user group for GuestUser named GuestAccounts.
2. In D partition properties go to 'Security' tab. Then press 'Advanced'.
3. Press 'Change permissions', then add some restriction for GuestAccounts (or just GuestUser).

That's all :)

Thanks Scott for your advices! :)